# Why doesnt my text editor save?

Tags: python, text, tkinter

Im kinda a python noob, and im trying to make a simple text editor for my school, but saving, cutting, pasting, and copying don't work. Its called PyWriter and im using Tkinter. Sorry for not adding code comments. Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox

def __init__(self):
    self.text = textPad()
    self.text.pack()
root = Tkinter.Tk(className=" PyWriter")
textPad = ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=80)


def open_command():
    file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Open')
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        textPad.insert('1.0',contents)
        file.close()

def save_command(self):
    file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(parent=root,mode='w',title='Save')
    if file != None:
        data = self.textPad.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()

def exit_command():
    root.destroy()

def copy_command(self, event=None):
    self.clipboard_clear()
    text = self.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
    self.clipboard_append(text)

def cut_command(self, event=None):
    self.copy()
    self.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")

def paste_command(self, event=None):
    text = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
    self.insert('insert', text)


menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=open_command)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save...", command=save_command)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy_command)
filemenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=cut_command)
filemenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste_command)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit_command)

textPad.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide some information about the way in which it doesn't work; what errors do you get, what is wrong with the functionality etc.

Comment: you should be very sorry about the code comments ;-P

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter GUI's are often coded without using classes although I would recommend to use them.
You have a mix of both kind of approaches probably due to cuts and pastes.
To give you an idea of what is wrong in your code I give you below examples following the two different approaches. I only fixed the copy/paste methods, the rest is work for you.

Without classes (I don't consider this good code):

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText

def copy_command():
    root.clipboard_clear()
    text = textPad.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
    root.clipboard_append(text)

def paste_command():
    text = root.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
    textPad.insert('insert', text)

root = tk.Tk(className=" PyWriter")

textPad = ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=80)

menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

filemenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy_command)
filemenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste_command)

textPad.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and with classes:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText

class TkApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, className=" PyWriter"):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, className=className)
        self.textPad = ScrolledText(self, width=100, height=80)
        self.textPad.pack()

        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=self.copy_command)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.paste_command)

    def copy_command(self):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        text = self.textPad.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
        self.clipboard_append(text)

    def paste_command(self):
        text = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
        self.textPad.insert('insert', text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TkApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this (and other similar errors):

```
def save_command(self):
```

Your function takes one argument, but the button doesn't pass an argument to it, so it throws an error.

My guess is, you incorrectly copied this code from somewhere else. It has all of the markings of a class, but you don't have a `class` statement. You have an `__init__` function which will only get called when you instantiate a class, and your functions have `self` as their only parameter, which is typically what you do for methods of object.

My suggestion is to take a closer look at where you copied bits of this code, and you'll find that probably immediately before the `__init__` function you'll see something like `class Something():`

Comment: ok, Thanks. PS: i didn't copy and paste, i looked at code examples